# "Logging In" From a Console Plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I am writing a console plugin to import a load of gallery images from an old site into a new craft site. I need to create folders in the assets area, import the images, then create custom entries to represent the galleries.

I am hitting a hurdle at the first task, creating a folder. It fails with a general message like "Error creating folder". I assume it's because I am not "logged in" and therefore have no permission to create the assets folder.

So I tried to do a `craft()->userSession->loginByUserId(1)` but I got the complaint about no ip address or user agent string. I checked the code and saw that there is a config item to turn this check off, but the method `loginByUserId()` doesn't use it.

Is there a way to force a login from a console plugin so that I can do privileged operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craft 2 doesn't really have the concept of sessions or logging in for it's console app.

If I had to guess that error is more about file system permissions, but you'd want to check your log files for a full stack trace to see where it's originating from.